# "Me" or "I" in one-word answers

Tags: pronouns

I've just read a couple of questions concerning the proper usage of the pronouns "I" and "me" in sentences like:

> John and I went fishing

It seems clear and obvious to me, that when the pronoun is the subject of the sentence, we should use the subject pronoun.

My question concerns a different context, though. I'm curious as to which pronoun is correct when used in a short, one-word answer? So, when we hear a question like "Who wants to go fishing tomorrow?", should the answer be:

> Me!

or

> I!

My intuition tells me it should be the former, but I don't really know why.
Is there any underlying rule in English, that dictates which pronoun - subject or object - should be used in the above-mentioned context?

Comment: Forget analysis (eg ... want to go fishing condenses to ...). Using 'I!' here makes you sound ridiculous. 'Me!' (or, if you want to sound less informal, 'I do!'

Comment: It's a question of *grammatical?* or *acceptable?*! **I** is grammatical and **Me** is acceptable. ( (It's) Me; I (do) - the question is **who wants?** ( the subject form) and the grammatical answer is **I** (the subject form))

Comment: @mahmud koya - We only use the subject form in sentences, like "I do."   If the answer is a fragment (no verb) then we just say "Me."

Answer (score 0):

When a sentence fragment is devoid of verbals (modals or [aux] verbs), subject case marking is avoided (even when the fragment fills in the subject of a question).

Comment: Citations required to substantiate the answer.