# "Me too" or "I too"?

Tags: british-english

On the club channel, someone has asked who will come on Wednesday. One of the members replied: "I will be there on Wednesday.". Which form is correct: "I too" or "Me too" ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Who wants ice-cream?" — Should I say "(not) I" or "(not) me"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4556/who-wants-ice-cream-should-i-say-not-i-or-not-me) or ['Me' or 'I' in one-word answers?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/388341/me-or-i-in-one-word-answers)?

Comment: Strictly speaking, "I [will be] too" is correct, but would sound rather pretentious, so in everyday speech most people would say "Me too".

Comment: Everyday speech eventually determines what's correct. 'I, too' would mark someone out in a wrong way, unless they were being intentionally affected.

Comment: You could look at *Me, too* this way: "I will be there on Wednesday." "That applies to me, too."

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: No one is mentioning: **So do I.**

Comment: @Lambie The reason being OP asks ' "I will be there on Wednesday." Which form is correct: "I too" or "Me too"?'